# Not able to see extra elements in the menu in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, listener, jmeter-plugins

As part of my project requirement, I need to generate various graphs. Since JMeter does not have enough reporting methods, I downloaded the plugin  from http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/ and I kept the Jar file in the path `'D:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext'` after that I restarted a couple of times but still I couldn't see the new elements under listener tab.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have placed 'Plugin-Manager' Jar files to your JMeter path. It is not the plugin itself but just a plugin manager.

If you want to have extra listeners directly, without using plugin install manager then you should download the following from JMeter-Plugin old releases page ([Click Here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/old/)):

```
JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.4.0.zip
JMeterPlugins-Extras-1.4.0.zip
```

Unzip these and place the JAR files to your JMeter directory. Restart the JMeter and you ll have the additional listeners that you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the plugin manager under options in the menu. From the pluginsmanager you can download plugins like Graphs Generator Listener.